# How can I do dynamic badge on React CoreUI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, core-ui

I have a problem with a badge on Core UI. I have a Sidebar and one of the elements is `Chat`. When a new message comes, the badge must show *new message*. But the old developer have written different ways and I can not change it. I cannot find anything for this.

My codes
Sidebar elements

```
const _nav = [
  {
    _tag: "CSidebarNavItem",
    name: "Chat",
    to: "/chat",
    filter: "feedbacks",
    icon: "cil-speech",
    badge: {
      color: "info",
      text: "NEW MESSAGE",
    },
  },
]
```

My React component

```
  import navigation from "./_nav";
  const [filteredNav, setFilteredNav] = useState([]);
  const [chatBadge, setChatBadge] = useState(false);

  const handleChatBadge = () => {
     setChatBadge(true)
  }

   // it is a sidebar element for user-role
   useLayoutEffect(() => {
    allwedMenu().then((res) => {
      const arr = [navigation[0]];
      res.data.items.forEach((element) => {
        arr.push(element.name);
      });
      setFilteredNav(navigation.filter((item) => arr.includes(item.filter)));
    });
  }, []);

  <CSidebarNav>
   <CCreateElement
              items={filteredNav}
              components={{
                CSidebarNavDivider,
                CSidebarNavDropdown,
                CSidebarNavItem,
                CSidebarNavTitle,
              }}
            />
    </CSidebarNav>
```

I need the badge to show when `chatBadge` is true. But I don't know how can I write this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only add a condition to show the badge when chatBadge is true.
Based on the Value of ChatBadge, you can use the property of the Component CSideBarNavItem to display the badge and pass the colour and text properties.

Here's the correct code:

```
<CSidebarNav>
  <CCreateElement
    items={filteredNav}
    components={{
      CSidebarNavDivider,
      CSidebarNavDropdown,
      CSidebarNavItem,
      CSidebarNavTitle,
    }}
  />
  {filteredNav.map((item, index) => (
    <CSidebarNavItem
      key={index}
      name={item.name}
      to={item.to}
      icon={item.icon}
      badge={
        item.name === "Chat" && chatBadge
          ? { color: "info", text: "NEW MESSAGE" }
          : null
      }
    />
  ))}
</CSidebarNav>
```

Hope it helps.